# How to convert a byte stream (binary form) to a CSV file using Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have to process a `.csv` file using `AWS Lambda function`. I serve the `.csv` file to the Lambda function using an `AWS API Gateway`. Now the API Gateway transforms the `.csv` file into a `base64 string` as it is received in the request. Any idea how to convert it back to `.csv` file.

I have mentioned my code below for reference.

```
import os
import sys

CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(CWD, "lib"))

import json
import base64
import boto3
import numpy as np
import io
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    
    # retrieving data from event which is base64 string
    get_file_content_from_postman = event["content"]
    
    # decoding data. Here the file content is converted back to binary form
    binary_file= base64.b64decode(get_file_content_from_postman)
```

Comment: How exactly does it work? Are you sure `event["content"]` is valid? I don't think API gateway has even such a fileld.

Comment: I've added a mapping template with this name like { "content" : "$input.body"} so that the API Gateway will allow only those files which have content-type as  text/csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `binary_file` will by `bytes`, you can just wrap it in `BytesIO` to treat it as  a file for your pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(binary_file))
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Your provided solution worked!